# Get element attribute names from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to write a generic function that works with JSON arrays containing arbitrary attributes. Given the following:

```
var propMap = '{"ddColor": "Color","ddSize": "Size", "ddOther": "Other"}'
```

How can I iterate through the attributes and their values without specifying either? In other words, I want to iterate the elements without specifying "ddColor", "ddSize" or "ddOther". Yet, I want to iterate both the name and its value.

I've looked all over for a solution, but can't find one and also can't make it work on jsFiddle:

```
var propMap = '{"ddColor": "Color","ddSize": "Size"}'

for(var x in propMap) {
    // Key: x
    // Value: propMap[x]
    alert(x + ': ' + propMap[x]);
}
```

When I run the above code it seems to iterate character by character. Example:

```
1: C
2: o
3: l
4: o
5: r
```

Comment: Just to be clear, there is no such thing as a JSON array. There are JSON strings, and they can represent arrays or objects.

Comment: I said you'll need to parse the JSON first if you haven't already, using `jQuery.parseJSON`. (See the bottom part of my answer, plus the jsFiddle.)

Comment: Thanks Jonathon. Wasn't sure about the right terminology. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use a [`for in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
for (var x in propMap) {
    if (propMap.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        // Key: x
        // Value: propMap[x]
    }
}
```

And if that's actually a string, you'll need to parse the JSON first, of course:

```
propMap = jQuery.parseJSON(propMap);
```

[Here's a jsFiddle, too.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/Nkd4h/)

Comment: If not using jQuery, [`json2.js`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) is the simplest way to get a safeish JSON parser.

Comment: @millimoose: The question is tagged [tag:jquery], though.

Comment: I usually just use `JSON.parse()`. Is it considered unsafe?

Comment: @xbonez: It's absolutely safe, but it doesn't work on IE 8 and earlier.

Comment: Tried your example on jsFiddle. Edited my question to show the result. I see the new comments, yes I'm working in JQuery. I believe my string to be JSON. I can use .parseJSON. I'll take a look at your jsFiddle link.

Comment: Ah! The new example works. Thank you! Except I see a comment that this doesn't work on IE8 or before. I'm targeting all major browsers including IE7 and higher. I didn't know JSON/JQuery we dependent on browsers in this way. That's disappointing to know... (btw, I've only been learning JQuery/Javascript for about 2 weeks).

Comment: @rwkiii: `JSON.parse` doesn't work on IE 8. *`jQuery.parseJSON`* works on IE 8. (And IE 7. And probably IE 6.)

Comment: So your jsFiddle example is fairly compatible. Nice. Thank you minitech.

Comment: No problem :) Always happy to help. And if you need to use jQuery's `parseJSON` without jQuery and you trust the source of the JSON, `eval('(' + json + ')')` works in all browsers.